# How to teach a course or courses that I have not formally taken myself?

Tags: postdocs, teaching, coursework

I am currently a postdoc. My PhD research has been using Finite element method for additive manufacturing simulations.

I come from materials engineering background and I don't have any formal education on continuum mechanics or finite element method. I had taken some advanced courses on mechanics. But, they did not cover anything related to finite element analysis or continuum mechanics.

My self study on these topics are neither structured or formalized. I read books, online videos, tried some coding and concentrated on portions applicable for my research. I have forgotten most of the theory part.

As a result, I know how to model my problem statement, publish papers and develop new problem statements. But I know nothing many topics that is covered in an actual finite element course. Also, I did not do many example problems or coded my own programs (just 1d or 2d case).

Now, if I get an opportunity to teach students on the theoretical aspects of the finite element, how can I be confident that I can do a good job?

I have very limited teaching experience and I have taught only materials engineering courses. Please advise.

Comment: Perhaps you can find your answer here (a question asked and answered at CSEducators):https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/q/4379/1293